# Cutting video with ffmpeg makes shift in frame number

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pyffmpeg

I try to cut a video at 59,94 fps at specific frames with ffmpeg.

However in the final output I get a shift (approximately 30 frames shift) and I don't understand why.

My code is :

```
print(os.listdir('C:/Users/sgris/Downloads'))

(
ffmpeg
.input('C:/Users/sgris/Downloads/apid/18-2-19 6.04pm.MTS')
.trim(start_frame = 36435, end_frame = 36786)
.setpts('PTS-STARTPTS')
.output('C:/Users/sgris/Downloads/testtest2.mp4')
.run()
)
```

Comment: How have you identified start and end frame indices?

Comment: Frames were identified using VirtualDub software